# Faster way to split a numpy array according to a threshold

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Suppose I have a random numpy array:

```
X = np.arange(1000)
```

and a threshold:

```
thresh = 50
```

I want to split `X` in two partitions `X_l` and `X_r` in such a way that every element in `X_l` is less or equal to `thresh` while in `X_r` each element is greater than `thresh`. After that these two partitions are given to a recursive function.

Using numpy I create a boolean array and I use it to partition `X`:

```
Z = X <= thresh
X_l, X_r = X[Z == 0], X[Z == 1]
recursive_call(X_l, X_r)
```

This is done several times, is there a way to make things faster? Is it possible to avoid creating a copy of the partitions at each call?

Comment: As written, your code puts the small values (`<= thresh`) into `X_l` and the large values into `X_r`. Is this intentional?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`X[~Z]` is faster than `X[Z==0]`:

```
In [13]: import numpy as np

In [14]: X = np.random.random_integers(0, 1000, size=1000)

In [15]: thresh = 50

In [18]: Z = X <= thresh

In [19]: %timeit X_l, X_r = X[Z == 0], X[Z == 1]
10000 loops, best of 3: 23.9 us per loop

In [20]: %timeit X_l, X_r = X[~Z], X[Z]
100000 loops, best of 3: 16.4 us per loop
```

Have you [profiled](http://docs.python.org/2/library/profile.html) to determine that this is really the bottleneck in your code? If your code is spending only 1% of its time doing this splitting operation, then however much you optimize this operation will have no more than a 1% impact on the overall performance.

You might benefit more by rethinking your algorithm or data structures than optimizing this one operation. And if this is really the bottleneck, you might also do better by rewriting this piece of [code in C](http://docs.python.org/2/extending/extending.html) or [Cython](http://docs.cython.org/src/userguide/memoryviews.html)...

When you have numpy arrays of size 1000, there is a *chance* that using Python lists/sets/dicts might be quicker. The speed benefit of NumPy arrays sometimes does not become apparent until the arrays are quite large. You might want to rewrite your code in pure Python and benchmark the two versions with [timeit](http://docs.python.org/2/library/timeit.html).

Hm, let me rephrase that. It's not really the size of the array which makes NumPy quicker or slower. Its just that having small NumPy arrays is sometimes a sign that you are creating *lots* of small NumPy arrays, and the creation of a NumPy array is significantly slower than the creation of, say, a Python list:

```
In [21]: %timeit np.array([])
100000 loops, best of 3: 4.31 us per loop

In [22]: %timeit []
10000000 loops, best of 3: 29.5 ns per loop

In [23]: 4310/295.
Out[23]: 14.610169491525424
```

Also, when you code in pure Python, you might be more likely to use dicts and sets for which there is no direct NumPy equivalent. That might lead you to an alternative algorithm which is quicker.

Comment: Thank you. This is at least a speed up.

Comment: Be careful!  This gives the larger values to `X_l` and the smaller values to `X_r`.  I think the @bluenot20 intended the opposite, even though it's backwards in the question too.

Comment: That Cython link is out of date. That technique may actually be removed in Cython 2.0. You should use [`memoryview`s](http://docs.cython.org/src/userguide/memoryviews.html) now.

Answer (score 1):

Is your array always already sorted?  In your example you use `arange`, which is sorted, so there's no need to do boolean indexing, you can simply slice your array in half at the appropriate location.  This avoids using 'advanced indexing' so you don't have to copy the array.

```py
X = np.arange(0, 2*thresh)
i = X.searchsorted(thresh, side='right') # side='right' for `<=`
X_l, X_r = X[:i], X[i:]
```

This saves a lot of time for sorted arrays, but obviously won't work otherwise:

```py
thresh = 500
X = np.arange(2*thresh)

%%timeit
i = X.searchsorted(thresh, side='right')
X_l, X_r = X[:i], X[i:]
100000 loops, best of 3: 5.16 µs per loop

%%timeit
Z = X <= thresh                         
X_l, X_r = X[Z], X[~Z]
100000 loops, best of 3: 12.1 µs per loop
```

Comment: What you should time is how both solutions depend on the size of the array. In case of slicing, `X[:i]` should be a 'view' into X, so the operation should cost more or less constant time. You only have to create a new array-object, which then points to a sub-set of the original vector, no data is actually copied.